# How to update a Postgres table with a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, dataframe

I have a table in postgres with some information already but I'm unable to update it without inserting the data line by line. This is what I'm doing:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("postgres://...")
cur = conn.cursor()

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    column_0 = df["column_0"].iloc[i]
    column_1 = df["column_1"].iloc[i]
    column_2 = df["column_2"].iloc[i]

    sql_command = f"INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('{column_0}', '{column_1}', '{column_2}')"
    cur.execute(sql_command.replace("'None'", 'NULL'))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I'm looking for a different way to send the information to the table since this is too slow and it's getting kinda long every time I need to add a new column to the table. I tried doing the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://...")


df.to_sql("my_table", engine, index=False, if_exists="replace")

engine.dispose()
```

While it seems to be doing something, when I try to do the query again, I get nothing new back, the table is not updating.

Comment: [This](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#results-summary) and/or [this](https://github.com/magicstack/asyncpg) if you want speed. If there's anything interacting with the table, [`.to_sql(...if_exists="replace")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) might be blocked waiting for the other transaction to finish before it can drop, recreate and repopulate the table.

Comment: 1) Per docs [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html): *replace: Drop the table before inserting new values. append: Insert new values to the existing table.* 2) Do you have to use a `dataframe`?

Comment: @Zegarek, I have tried dropping the table however, if execute the second block of code after dropping the table it doesn't happen anything, the command does not recreate the table but I don't get any errors either. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm getting my data in a dataframe so I assumed that would be the best to send it to postgres. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The issue is `to_sql` does INSERTS which is inherently slower for a data set of any size then using Postgres  `COPY`. The Pandas docs here [io-sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-sql) show an example of how to use `COPY` in the section: *Example of a callable using PostgreSQL COPY clause:*.

Comment: @AngelPeñaflor Please show how you build the dataframe, how you check its contents, how you upload it and verify it is (or isn't) uploaded (use mock/fake/sample data). If you take a look at the [first link](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#execute-values-from-iterator) I attached above, there's a handful of examples with benchmarks - try that if you need something the built-in `.to_sql()` doesn't offer. If you want even more speed, you can try the second link. Your current string interpolation approach is not just slow and inconvenient, it's also a security risk.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver [the pandas example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-sql) `.writerows()` the whole payload into memory. [The link](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#copy) I posted above addresses that and shows how to work around it: the alternative is not just more memory-efficient, it's faster.